# Phpmyadmin 403 forbidden

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, rackspace

I have a problem with installing phpmyadmin on my CentOS rackspace servers.

I have tried many solutions on the net and many from StackOverflow, but I always receive a 403 forbidden error. I tried installing MySQL again.

I tried the text below for my httpd.conf file.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

I tried disabling "SELINUX" and nothing seems to work.

My main web directory is "var/www/html/web".

Comment: Does the user that is running your web server have permission to (r) read and (X) Traverse the `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin`? Have you looked into `/var/logs/` for I assume your apache2/error_log?

Comment: hello dear hoss, how can i check (r) and (x) rights? i didn't get that sorry i am not an expert in this... i have logs in /var/log/httpd is it what you mean?

thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: From terminal if you `ls -l /usr/share` and look at this http://linuxcommand.org/images/permissions_diagram.gif also and `/var/logs/httpd` might be correct, just look for ny log files in there that look like error logs

Comment: Hello again, the rights are drwxr-xr-x, i also checked the error logs, nothing interesting there i guess: 

[Fri May 15 21:37:09 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri May 15 21:37:10 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri May 15 21:37:10 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri May 15 21:37:10 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 15 21:37:10 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

Thanks again for the help

Comment: Are you using the package manager to install phpMyAdmin or did you download it manually?

Comment: i used yum install...